# Обособление определений, относящихся к личному местоимению

Tags: пунктуация

Правило обособления определения говорит, что если определение относятся к личному местоимению, то оно **всегда (независимо ни от чего)** обособляется.

В предложении: *"Я второй стоял в очереди"*.

*Я* - подлежащее - главное (определяемое)слово;

*второй* - определение, выраженное порядковым числительным.

Значит, если я правильно понимаю, определение *"второй"* должно быть обособлено запятыми?
*Я, второй, стоял в очереди.*
Или я что-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 3):

1. *Я **вторОй** / стоял в очереди.*

Нет обособления, слово "второй" входит в состав сказуемого, сравнить: *Я **вторым** стоял в очереди.*

2. *Я, **второй**, стоял в очереди.*

Пр обособлении получается другой смысл: *Я, **второй номер**, стоял в очереди.*

**Интонация** тоже разная: логическое подчеркивание **ударением**  в первом варианте и **вставочная** интонация (с двумя паузами) во втором случае.